# How to automatically deploy maven project from eclipse to tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, maven

See title. I would also like the project to redeploy after every change. I am new to this area so my knowledge isnt that good. I tried googling and searching here, but I can't find any answer.

thanks for any help

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I think you should formulate your question as an answer, because M2E and WTP is the answer to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two plugins that combined together in Eclipse work quite well together to perform what you want:

1. [M2E](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/): M2Eclipse which handles everything related to Maven.
2. [Eclipse Web Tool Platform (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/): which handles everything Java EE related (Tomcat, JBoss, etc...)

For M2E to work properly with WTP, you need to add m2e-wtp. You may find several useful information as well as some good links [here](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp/wiki).

I would start from the Eclipse Java EE distribution (it includes already Eclipse-WTP) and then add M2E (either with their update site or through eclipse market place: look for M2E and M2E-WTP).

From there, you create a Web Project and you can run it on a Tomcat server. The first time you try to run you project on a server, you will install Tomcat and it will appear in view named "Server". Double click on the server to configure ports, automatic deployment etc...

Answer (score 3):

You can easily deploy a webapp using the [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) Tomcat plugin. Here's helpful articles on this topic:

[Maven Tomcat Deployment using Cargo plugin.](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/maven/maven-tomcat-deployment-using-cargo)

[Autodeployment with Maven, Tomcat, and Cargo.](http://dpillay.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/maven-cargo-tomcat-auto-deployment/)